# hive indexes error on partitioned table

Tags: indexing, hive

I was trying to test an example of hive indexes. I am not able to create indexes on a partitioned column but works on all other columns. Most of the sites gave examples on partitioned column but for some reason I am not able to get it worked. I am using hive 14 and the example was taken from Programming in hive. Can some one let me know if something is wrong in the below code?

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
name STRING,
salary FLOAT,
subordinates ARRAY<STRING>,
deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
address STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>
)
PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, state STRING);


CREATE INDEX employees_index
ON TABLE employees (country)
AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler'
WITH DEFERRED REBUILD
IDXPROPERTIES ('creator = 'me', 'created_at' = 'some_time')
IN TABLE employees_index_table
PARTITIONED BY (country, name)
COMMENT 'Employees indexed by country and name.';
```

Error :

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:0 missing EOF at 'PARTITIONED' near 'employees_index_table'
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 7:0 missing EOF at 'PARTITIONED' near 'employees_index_table'
```

Comment: IDXPROPERTIES ('creator = 'me', 'created_at' = 'some_time') i have taken care of the syntax error but still it aint working